# Producing slices of dot output without intermediates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large set of 3 x 3 matrices (`n` of them, say) and corresponding 3 x 1 vectors, and would like to multiply each vector by its corresponding matrix.  If I stack the matrices into a `n` x 3 x 3 `ndarray` called `R` and the vectors into a 3 x `n` `ndarray` called `v`, I can obtain the stack of multiplied vectors via,

```
import numpy as np
intermediate = np.dot(R, v)
out = np.diagonal(intermediate, axis1=0, axis2=2)
```

But this is very inefficient: `np.dot` produces the `n` x 3 x `n` `intermediate` array, out of which I then manually select a 3 x `n` slice.  Other than by looping over `n`, can I somehow produce the 3 x `n` array without making the intermediate `n` x 3 x `n` array?

Comment: Look at `np.einsum`.

Comment: @MattDMo, this doesn't avoid generating the intermediate array.  It just avoids assigning it a name.  But it still takes up memory, and requires compute to be constructed.

Comment: I'm still somewhat of a numpy newbie - like I said, wild guess :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the hint provided by @hpaulj: the multiplication I described can be carried out by,

```
out = np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', R, v)
```

The speedup over the approach in my question is already 3 orders of magnitude (!) for `n = 1000`:

```
%timeit d = np.diagonal(np.dot(R, v), axis1=0, axis2=2)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop

%timeit o = np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', R, v)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: Sometime in the not so distant future, using Python 3.5 and an upcoming numpy version, you could do: `out = R @ v.T[:, None, :]`, see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).